# sql script cancelled by user after a couple of seconds

Tags: sql-server

I ran a script ( running manually ) having at the beginning of its code some set values like this:

```
DECLARE @blahblah int

SET @blahblah = 0
```

The above value has a key role in the changes I would like to make. It creates new rows/entries in some table.

The table on the database I ran this script is huge / the database is also.

My question: Let's say I had put a wrong value to @blahblah, I ran the script and after 2 seconds I cancelled it immediatly. Then I corrected the @blahblah value and ran it again.

DId the trigger managed to change some entities/rows ( in the 2 seconds time ) or it was cancelled entirely?

Comment: Did you bundle those updates into Transactions?
Is this actually a trigger or a script that you ran manually - showing us the declaration for the variable is of no real help

Comment: @CHill60 : it is a script which runs manually. Sorry for not mention it

Comment: "the trigger" - what trigger? The only mention of triggers in this question is that sentence and the fact it's tagged [tag:triggers].

Answer (score 1):

Depends, whether you have wrapped your DML inside a transaction block or not. If you have used transaction then probably the changes have been rolledback and your DB state should be consistent else, there may be partial changes happened to your table(s).

you should check and verify the same against your table(s).